# Dealing with UTF-8 file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, utf-8, decode, encode

8 gods and goddesses,

I have a csv file is is rumoured to be encoded in Win UTF-8.  I need to apply a bunch of reg exps and other sorts of string/array manipulation to it and then have it output again in WIN UTF-8.  I'm running Ruby 1.8 on Mac Lion. Are there any gotchas that I should be aware of?  I got no UTF-8 fu.

Ok, so win utf-8 shocked everyone else as it did me.  What about UTF-8? anyone? anyone?

Thanks in advance
Mark

Comment: What the !@#%@ is **Win** UTF-8?

Comment: @tchrist: Probably a CSV file in UTF-8 with Windows CRLF line endings.

Comment: now you understand my angst... @mu can't upgrade to 1.9 - please don't make me go into details on why :P

Comment: There's no such thing as "Win UTF-8".

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your problem is.

Ruby 1.8 has native support for UTF-8. Actually it the only format it can work with internally. Otherwise you can always use iconv to convert between encodings. If the format is something different than UTF-8 you have to use iconv for input and output.

Regarting CSV, I think that fastercsv is a really neat framework for that, as it covers all corner cases and allows you to customize the in-/output format.

Depending on how many of these files you have to edit it might be faster to just use some texteditor to convert your file to standard UTF-8 with Unix style endings. Then you can apply your changes and convert it back with your editor.

Comment: I'm not sure how good the Unicode regex support is in 1.8, 1.9 uses [Oniguruma](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/) which has all the bells and whistles (such as `\p{Alnum}` and such). And FasterCSV (with some Unicode improvements) is 1.9's standard CSV.

Comment: Fully intend to use fastercsv to massage the file but wasn't aware that 1.8 has native support for utf-8.  Let me give it a go.  Thanks.